# Is it possible to get 'csr' info from SSL certificate in web browser?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

When creating a csr you provide some information about Country,company, email, etc. 
Then when the certificate files are installed in i.e. apache , you browse to the url and see i.e. in chrome the green lock, you click it and see some registrant info, but you don't see any of the data you entered when creating csr file.

Is it possible to read that data (country, company) somehow just from browser/SSL ?

Comment: Look at the subject part of the certificate details. How you access these depends on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers wont show all the details you have entered at the time of creating CSR. It will show limited details like Common domain name, certificate authority etc. In order to get complete details, you will need either CSR key or Certificate.

If you have CSR key, you can enter the CSR key at following URL and get complete details:

[CSR Decoder](https://www.sslshopper.com/csr-decoder.html)

If you have Certificate, you can enter the Certificate at following URL and get complete details:

[Certificate Decoder](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html)

Thanks,

Comment: Browsers show you the contents of the certificate if you view the certificate details.

Comment: The issue here is that many certificate issuers don't copy all CSR fields to the final certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can review the information through the browser. The subject section of the CSR is visible in IE, Firefox, Chrome for Windows XP through Windows 10.  The browsers that work on multiple OS versions are usually very similar in how to view the certificate information. Ex. the steps for Firefox in Linux is the same as windows.

Make sure you establish an SSL connection to the site you want to see details for.

OpenSSL parameters for CSR generation.  The subject contains the information you have requested.

-subj "/C=US/ST='state'/L='city'/O='company name' LLC/OU='Division of company ex Information Technology' /CN=www.yoursitename.com"

For recent versions of Chrome click the area in front of the domain [may show in green if it is an EV certificate], section prior to https://. Then select connection; select 'certificate information'; select the 'Details' tab - you will now see a list of properties - arrow down to the subject and you will see the information submitted in the CSR.

IE. While in an SSL connection: Click the lock - Select view certificate - Select 'Details' tab - arrow down to the subject line

Firefox - While in an SSL connection - click in front of the domain; usually a lock symbol - select more information - select View Certificate button - Select 'Details' tab - arrow down to the Subject

Firefox in Linux - Click the lock - select more information - select View Certificate button - Select Details - arrow down to Subject